# How do you add an auto-incrementing ID column to a table of data extracted from a separate table in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a table in Oracle SQL that stores a list of distinct month and year combinations extracted from a date column in an existing table, alongside a Time ID  to denote that specific month and year from other tables. However, I'm having some trouble with doing this, and would appreciate some advice on other methods to try.

I have already worked out how to extract each distinct month and year from the table. I used the following SQL syntax to do this, and it worked successfully:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) Month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) Year FROM ExistingTable;
```

When I tried this, it successfully selected each distinct month and year combination from the existing table.

I was also successful in creating a table from just these two values, using the CREATE TABLE AS command as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE DatesTable AS SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) Month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) Year FROM ExistingTable;
```

This successfully created a table storing each distinct month and year combination from the existing table.

However, I then tried to add an auto-incrementing TimeID column to the table, and this is where I began to encounter issues.

I should preface this by saying that I created the following sequence to auto-increment ID values:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AutoIncrementTimeID MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 10;
```

From prior experience, I know that this style of sequence works for auto-incrementing ID values, so I don't think that my sequence is causing the issues.

I firstly tried creating a schema, containing TimeID, Month and Year with TimeID as a primary key, and populating the table with the existing table month and year combinations alongside a sequenced TimeID, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE DatesTable (TimeID INTEGER NOT NULL, Month INTEGER NOT NULL, Year INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(TimeID));

INSERT INTO DatesTable (TimeID, Month, Year) VALUES (AutoIncrementTimeID.nextval, SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) FROM ExistingTable);
```

The table was created successfully, but the INSERT INTO command returned the following error:

```
ORA-00936: Missing expression
```

Next, I tried integrating the next value of the auto-increment sequence into the CREATE TABLE AS sequence displayed above, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE DatesTable AS SELECT DISTINCT AutoIncrementTimeID.nextval TimeID, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) Month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) Year FROM ExistingTable;
```

However, when I tried this, the following error was returned:

```
ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
```

I then considered creating the table with just the month and year columns and using the ALTER TABLE command to add an ID column to the table retrospectively, but it then dawned upon me that Oracle would not allow me to add a non-nullable ID column due to the impact on the existing data.

I will admit that I'm now a little bit stuck for ideas having tried these solutions and had them not work. Does anyone know how I could create a table that adds an auto-incrementing Time ID column alongside the distinct month and year values extracted from the existing table? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

That's because you have `DISTINCT`. If you want to do this you need to get the distinct values in a subquery, then add the sequence reference in the outer query:

```
CREATE TABLE DatesTable AS
SELECT AutoIncrementTimeID.nextval TimeID, Month, Year
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date_col) Month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date_col) Year
  FROM ExistingTable
);
```

You can do the same thing with the separate create and insert, which currently gives

> ORA-00936: Missing expression

because you are mixing the `VALUES` and `SELECT` syntax for an insert statement; instead you can do:

```
INSERT INTO DatesTable (TimeID, Month, Year)
SELECT AutoIncrementTimeID.nextval TimeID, Month, Year
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date_col) Month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date_col) Year
  FROM ExistingTable
);
```

If you're on a recent version of Oracle you can use an identity column instead of your own sequence:

```
CREATE TABLE DatesTable (
  TimeID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Month INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Year INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

and then a simpler insert works:

```
-- note TimeID not listed - handled by identity column
INSERT INTO DatesTable (Month, Year)
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date_col), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date_col) FROM ExistingTable;
```

(In order versions you can use a trigger to achieve the same effect.)

Alternatively, if this is a one-off operation then you can skip the sequence completely and use an analytic function to generate a row number, which also lets you order the ID with the values if you want, and avoids gaps etc. (not that either should matter if this is a synthetic key):

```
CREATE TABLE DatesTable (TimeID INTEGER NOT NULL, Month INTEGER NOT NULL, Year INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(TimeID));
```

```
INSERT INTO DatesTable (TimeID, Month, Year)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Year, Month) TimeID, Month, Year
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date_col) Month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date_col) Year
  FROM ExistingTable
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uSG7VMGm) showing all of those with some simple data.

---

You might want to rethink this, depending on what you're going to use this table for. It might be simpler to have a single `Year_Month` value, which you can get with `select distinct trunc(date_col, 'MM')` - those are then date values, representing midnight on the first day of each of those months;  easier to compare with dates in other tables, and they can act as the primary key without needing another ID column.